# MVC 4 How to access model's required attribute client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am already marking properties of my models with the required attribute.  Is there a way to access this information client side?  My goal is to have some kind of indicator on what fields are required/not required(like a * by a Html.EditorFor or something).  I want to avoid simply going into the views and adding the indicator because I would like to keep the required stuff in one location(the model).  Thanks.

Is assigning a css rule rule my only option?

Comment: may be you need to write a custom version of Html.LabelFor helper method

Comment: That's a good idea except I am mostly using  Html.EditorForModel().  Is there some way I could override how EditorForModel renders labels or do I need to customize that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the `data-required` attribute in CSS, since the attribute is added to the HTML generated by MVC for required properties.

I haven't done this before, but the CSS selector might look like this:

```
[data-required="true"]
```

Hope this helps, let me know how it goes.

Comment: See my answer but the selector you mentioned helped me solve.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it to work with this javascript and jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $(':input[data-val-required]').each(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var selector = 'label[for=' + name + ']';
        var label = $(selector).first();
        var innerHtml = label.html() + '*';
        label.html(innerHtml);
    });
})
```

The idea is that the input has "data-val-required" when the [Required] attribute is added to the model.  When you use:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.VendorId) %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.VendorId) %>
```

The html will have look like this:

```
<div>
    <label for="VendorId">Vendor Id</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="VendorId" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="VendorId" data-val-required="The Vendor Id field is required." data-val-length-max="255" data-val-length="The Vendor Id field can't exceed 255 characters." data-val="true"></input>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="VendorId"></span>
</div>
```

Notice that the input 'name' ('id' would also work) and label 'for' match so use this to alter the labels html with jquery.